# Distributing Electron Application Across Platforms

Tags: electron

I developed an application on my Macbook and I followed the [Application Distribution](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.33.0/tutorial/application-distribution/) page instructions on the Electron website. So right now when I double click on my electron.app folder it runs my application perfectly. However, when I transfer that folder to my Windows machine, it just shows a folder. When I double click on the folder it just shows me its contents. How can the package be run on the Windows? I don't care about my code being exposed to others. I just want to be able to run it on Windows. Is the only way of doing so through making an exe file?

Answer (score 1):

Electron has separate binary distributions for Windows, OS X, and Linux, as seen on its [releases page](https://github.com/atom/electron/releases).  You will need to bundle your application's code under the `resources` folder in each distribution for each platform you want to release for.

[electron-packager](https://github.com/maxogden/electron-packager) exists to make this process a lot less labor-intensive.

Comment: Also see the `electron-builder` project. https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-builder